# Comando finddo matlab em python?

Tags: python-3.x

Qual o equivalente em *python3.6* do comando `find` do *matlab* para esta expressão? O *PDF* que tenho com algumas equivalências não tem este comando

```
pos = find(sn_til>0)
```

Answer (score 1):

O [find de matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/find-array-elements-that-meet-a-condition.html) devolve a posição dos elementos que satisfazem uma condição particular.

Uma maneira simples de implementar seria:

```
vals = [1,2,5,64,33,2,4,-1,3,-54,21] 
vals_find = [idx for idx, val in enumerate(vals) if val > 0] # armazenamos os indices em que se encontram os valores que satisfazem a condição
print(vals_find) # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10]
```

Em que a condição é `val > 0`

Em matlab os indices começam em 1, se quiseres o resultado com base nisso, podes alterar para:

```
vals_find = [idx for idx, val in enumerate(vals, 1) if val > 0]
```